# Main method not found in class exo1.Batiment, please define the main method as:public static void main(String[] args) or a JavaFX application class

Tags: java

Hey guys please i have a problem when running a java programme ( am new to java ) :
when i run the code on eclipse it shows me the error above about the main not found but i have a main in my programme and declared as static there is my code ( the names ar in french am sorry ) :

```
package exo1;

public class Batiment {

    String adresse ;
    int surfaceHabitable ;

    public Batiment(String adresse , double surface) {
        this.adresse = adresse ;
        this.surfaceHabitable = (int) surface ;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "-- L'adresse est : " + adresse + "\n" + "-- La surface habitable est : " + surfaceHabitable + " metre carres\n"  ;
    }


     class Maison extends Batiment {
        int nbPieces;
        int surfaceJardin;

        public Maison(String adresse, int surfaceH, int surfaceJ, int nbPieces) {
            super(adresse, surfaceH);
            this.nbPieces = nbPieces;
            this.surfaceJardin = surfaceJ;
        }

         public String toString() {
            return super.toString() + "-- La surface du jardin est : " + surfaceJardin + " metre carres" + "\n-- Le nombre de pieces est : " + nbPieces  ;
        }
}
    class Immeuble extends Batiment{
        int nbAppart ;

        public Immeuble(String adresse, int surface, int numAppart) {
            super(adresse, surface);
            this.nbAppart = numAppart ;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return super.toString() + "-- Le numero d'apparetement est : " + nbAppart ;
        }
    }

    public static class TestBatiment{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Batiment B1 = new Batiment("app 5 imm riad res rabat CYM", 100);
            Maison M1 = B1.new Maison("app 5 imm riad res rabat CYM", 90, 50, 5);
            Immeuble I1 = B1.new Immeuble("app 5 imm riad res rabat CYM", 100, 5);
            System.out.println(B1);
            System.out.println(M1);
            System.out.println(I1);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: It needs to be inside public class Batiment not the internal class public static class TestBatiment

Comment: but in the question they told us to create a main method inside a new class TestBatiment

Comment: okay then tell eclipse your main method is in exo1.Batiment.TestBatiment not exo1.Batiment

Comment: and how i should do that cuz i dont know how to tell eclipse that

Answer (score 0):

your code put in a single file does compile without errors so i suppose you are not trying to run the good java file (which is the TestBatiment one)